# Installshield 2013 LE (copy/ backup setup.exe)

Tags: c#, installshield

I'm using to Install Shield 2013 Limited Edition to create an installer of my C# (Windows Form) application.

I already set all options and can successfully install the application with the generated (SingleImage) setup.exe file.

My question: Is it possible to hold/ create a copy/ backup of the setup.exe file in a (installation) folder of the application?

So after installation:

Main application folder

- Program   (sub folder) (contains all necessary files to run the application)
- Documents (sub folder) (contains documents as readme.txt)
- Setup BackUp (sub folder) (contains a copy of the setup.exe file as backup)

Do I need to set an option or how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do use Setup project instead of install shield. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-rEZ4Ir_PQ

Comment: That's a great alternative, but I want to achieve it with Installshield since I already have a setup.exe and set all parameters.

Comment: Actually set project let you include your prerequisites, reference files and your optional files. In optional files you can select your setup.exe too.